# Flutter Firebase Authentication: delay on startup

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using Provider and the stream FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged in the app to decide where to redirect on startup, but although the user is already logged in (from a previous startup) the app starts on the login screen and almost 1 second later redirects to the home page, from which it should have started from the first moment. This happens even in airplane mode.

I would like to know if there is any approach to solve this, even if it is not possible to show the home screen at once, I don't know how to differentiate between the not logged user (null->login screen) and loading user (null->loading screen).

Some of the code:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final DatabaseService db = DatabaseService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
      value: _auth.onAuthStateChanged,
      child: Consumer<FirebaseUser>(
        builder: (context, firebaseUser, child) {
          return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              if (firebaseUser != null)
                ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => CollectionState(firebaseUser)),
              StreamProvider<List<Collection>>.value(value: db.streamCollections(firebaseUser)),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
              title: 'My App',
              routes: {
                '/': (ctx) => LandingPage(),
                '/login': (ctx) => LoginPage(),
                '/emailSignIn': (ctx) => EmailSignInPage(),
                '/emailSignUp': (ctx) => EmailSignUpPage(),
                '/emailUnverified': (ctx) => EmailUnverifiedPage(),
                '/home': (ctx) => HomePage(),
                '/settings': (ctx) => Settings(),
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final DatabaseService _db = DatabaseService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);
    final userCondition =
        user == null ? 'null' : user.isEmailVerified ? 'verifiedUser' : 'unverifiedUser';

    switch (userCondition) {
      case 'null':
        return LoginPage();
        break;
      case 'unverifiedUser':
        return EmailUnverifiedPage();
        break;
      case 'verifiedUser':
        return HomePage();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

The code is a bit simplified, I use a service for the authentication instance instead, just that.

Comment: SharedPreferrence

Comment: Thanks for your reply meditat. Can you explain a little bit more?

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm very late, but I've had the same problem for weeks and I finally figured it out.

@ChinkySight is right when he says it's best to use a `StreamBuilder`, mostly because you have access to the connectionState property.

The reason why lag exists is because the connection to the stream is not fully established. So during ConnectionState.waiting, return a widget like a splash screen or just a container.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          // Added this line
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container();
          }
          if (snapshot.data is FirebaseUser && snapshot.data != null) {
            return HomePage();
          }
          return LoginPage();
        });
  }
}
```

You can even give your return statements fancy animations with the Animated Switcher

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        Widget widget;

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Container();
        }

        switch (snapshot.hasData) {
          case (true):
            widget = HomePage();
            break;
          case (false):
            widget = LoginPage();
        }
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
            ),
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
              child: FadeTransition(
                  opacity: animation,
                  child: widget,
                ),
               );
              },
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Animated switcher is not working, so changed the code to:
return AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
          child: widget,
        );

Comment: That's a mistake. Its child is supposed to be FadeTransition. Let me edit the code. EDIT: Edited!!

Answer (score 1):

This works for [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state).

> Firebase Auth enables you to subscribe in realtime to this state via a
> Stream. Once called, the stream provides an immediate event of the
> user's current authentication state, and then provides subsequent
> events whenever the authentication state changes. To subscribe to
> these changes, call the authStateChanges() method on your FirebaseAuth
> instance:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'menu.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(
          MyApp()
        );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'TestApp',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: 
        StreamBuilder<auth.User>(
          stream: auth.FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<auth.User> snapshot) { 
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
              print("data exists");
              return HomePage();
            }
            else {
              return LoginPage();
            }
          },
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful